# MouseDown on Button makes it Hidden, MouseUp makes it visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button on a page:

```
<input id="PauseMe" type="image" src="pauseButton.png">
```

I want to add two functions to the button for MouseUp and MouseDown that will cause the button to go "invisible" when MouseDown event happens, and will return "visible" when the MouseUp event happens.

I have followed another stackoverflow to add:

```
jQuery.fn.visible = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', 'visible');
};

jQuery.fn.invisible = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
};
```

And then I invoke it with the following code:

```
$( "#PauseMe" ).mousedown(function() {
    $('#PauseMe').invisible();
});
$( "#PauseMe" ).mouseup(function() {
    $('#PauseMe').visible();
});
```

Unfortunately though, once mousedown event triggers, I do not seem to be able to trigger the mouseup event.

For context, I have a background image that the button sits on, and when mouse goes down and turns button invisible, it looks like the button is now part of the background image, and when mouse goes up it looks normal. I have seen this working on another site, but am unable to peek their source well enough to see how they managed it exactly other than they add and remove class to button instead of adding CSS attribute directly.

Comment: `<input />` is a Void element and is self-closing. Does not closes using `</button>`

Comment: Oops. Leftover code from when I originally implemented using <button></button> but then decided to use an image as the button instead. Thank you. Will remove from code and post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CSS `:active` pseudo selector

```css
#PauseMe:active {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input id="PauseMe" type="image" src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf">
```

`:active` seems a better solution because an Action Element can become active on tab (not only on click or mouse Events in general).

### The *display* and *visibility* problem:

Tl;Dr: **Use `opacity`**.

An element will prevent you from registering a mouseup Event (also applies to the mouseup from a Click Event) if the element got `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.

To achieve the same effect, but keep the events bubbling - **use CSS `opacity`** instead:

```js
jQuery.fn.visible = function() {
  return this.css('opacity', '1');
};
jQuery.fn.invisible = function() {
  return this.css('opacity', '0');
};

$("#PauseMe").on({
  mousedown() {
    $(this).invisible();
  },
  mouseup() {
   $(this).visible();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="PauseMe" type="image" src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will play around with this a bit, so far it seems to work for what I need in terms of visibility, but it does break the click() function on that button it seems. Converting click() to mousedown() technically makes the button "work" but activates on mousedown instead of an actual click function.

Comment: @oogly yes, click breaks if an element is invisible / hidden (The mouseup is not invoked )

Comment: I wish I knew how the site im using as a reference does it. They are able to hide via class add and unhide with class remove, but still maintain the click() function that the button's true purpose serves. Oh well, I will keep messing with this, but so far seems to be the answer.

Comment: @oogly perhaps by using `opacity`, not `visibility`.

Comment: I have not actually tried the opacity part yet, but I am getting to a solution with the visibility by altering my definition of a "button" and using some other elements. I will circle back around to opacity and try that too, but this appears to solve the issue. Thanks again!